# Can adaptive UI be used in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, ios8, adaptive-ui

Can adaptive UI or a subset of its functionality be used in iOS 7? I am not able to find much information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use adaptive layout in iOS 7, It will only work in iOS 8.